# Show property editor by click on property text box in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I am creating a touch application on a no-keyboard pc, where I use a `PropertyGrid` to manage classes to store / save the app configuration.
I need to edit the propertyline's rows with a custom keyboard that I created (not the system's) setting the class as `UITypeEditor`
Now the custom keyboard is showed when right button is clicked.

Is it possible to show when on the row  start edit (like textbox Enter event),
or when the row is selected ?

Answer (score 1):

The editor control which you see in `PropertyGrid` is a `GridViewEdit` control which is a child of `PropertyGridView` which is a child of the `PropertyGrid`.

You can find the edit control and assign an event handler to its `Enter` event. In this event, you can find the `SelectedGridItem` and then call its `EditPropertyValue` method which is responsible to show the `UITypeEditor`.

```
private void propertyGrid1_SelectedObjectsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = propertyGrid1.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Where(x => x.GetType().Name == "PropertyGridView").FirstOrDefault();

    var edit = grid.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Where(x => x.GetType().Name == "GridViewEdit").FirstOrDefault();

    edit.Enter -= edit_Enter;
    edit.Enter += edit_Enter;
}

private void edit_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = this.propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem;
    if (item.GetType().Name == "PropertyDescriptorGridEntry")
    {
        var method = item.GetType().GetMethod("EditPropertyValue",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        var grid = propertyGrid1.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Where(x => x.GetType().Name == "PropertyGridView").FirstOrDefault();

        method.Invoke(item, new object[] { grid });
    }
}
```

**Note:** For modal editors the `Enter` event is annoying and repeats over and over again. To avoid this you can use `Click` event of the control.

Also as another option you can rely on `SelectedGridItemChanged` event of `PropertyGrid` and check if `e.NewSelection.GetType().Name == "PropertyDescriptorGridEntry"` then call `EditPropertyValue` of the selected grid item using reflection.